# How to get all level of data from a dimension by MDX query

Tags: mdx, olap-cube

how to get all sub level of data ?
If Category and Date dimensions, if they have
             Category
                  -Sub Category
                        -Group
                            -Sub Group
and,
             Date
                  -Quoter
                     -Month
                         -Week

level like this.

If it so how to gel all Category and all Date levels data by MDX query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I got your question right, if [Category] is a dimension with a single hierarchy :

- [Category].members           ,all members of the hierarchy
- [Category].levels            ,all levels
- [Category].levels(0)         ,the first level ( [All] is existing )
- [Category].levels(0).members ,all members of the first level